# pycharm - how to trace hidden class method __get__

Tags: python, pycharm

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar_ref = self.bar  # Allocation occurs here
        self.x = 0.1

    def bar(self, _):
        self.x *= 1.2
```

[@wim said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952288/an-instance-of-object-creation-occurs-when-a-reference-to-a-bound-method-is-cre)

> The dotted attribute access `self.bar` is an invocation of descriptor `__get__`, creating a bound method.

How do I get Pycharm to show `__get__` being executed when debugging?

Comment: Depends o what you mean by _show `__get__` being executed_ and also what is the use-case here ?

Comment: I want to get a complete picture of what happens when `self.bar` is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant `__get__` method is implemented in C; it's [`func_descr_get`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Objects/funcobject.c#L617) in `Objects/funcobject.c`. PyCharm does not support stepping into code written in C.

I believe you could step into this code with a Python debug build and the [Cython GDB extension](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/debugging.html), or even with a Python debug build and regular GDB if you're okay with seeing *everything* from the raw C-level perspective, but you can't do it in PyCharm.

Comment: Is there a way to configure Pycharm to at least inform me when it executes any C methods?

Comment: @Adrian: Pretty sure that's a no. PyCharm doesn't see that deep into the C.